# CarrierWave using s3 before_action rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I got a problem of encodage using Carrierwave for load an avatar for a user in rails.
I've follow this tutorial http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads
and this one for config my amazon accound 
https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave
I would like to upload my avatar just after that the user update it for only send the picture url to my db.
I've see that it's possible to use before_action but I don't see how :(
can I do this from my user controller after that i have update my params?
Thank you!

Comment: are you looking for this? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters

Comment: Thank! I've see that i can use before_action and send_file but i don't know how to link my amazon accound with this. I've just start to using rails.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters) to see how `before_action` works.

To "link" your account with the amazon web services you can read in the carrierwaves description: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#using-amazon-s3